# How to fix The difference between the request time and the current time is too large in Laravel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, datetime

I am using Laravel framework where I'm uploading files to Amazon S3 server. Its working fine in `localhost` and i have updated same thing in server. But I'm getting following error in server.

Server time is `09:25`  and my local system time is time is `12.50`

```
Exception thrown when handling an exception (ErrorException: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string)

RequestTimeTooSkewedException in NamespaceExceptionFactory.php line 91:
The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

I know I can fix this issue by updating server time. But I'm looking for ways to handle it in Laravel only, so server time doesn't effect other projects.

I have tried by updating `'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata'`, in `config/app.php` but it doesn't seems to be work.

Comment: Best is if you update server time. If you really want to use "laravel" to overcome this, I would say it will be very messy because signature signing is done deeply inside `aws-sdk-php` and you will need to overwrite quite a bit of classes to cheat the time. Some key classes involved are `S3SignatureV4`, `SignatureProvider`, `AwsClient`, `S3Client`.

Comment: @LionelChan.Thanks for respons